# How do I show mysql query results for fields that contain certain data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE genre = 'comedy' ORDER BY dateadded DESC";
```

I need to change it so that it selects from movielist where genre contains 'comedy'.

(Note: that my genre field will often contain more than one genre example "comedy, action, drama".

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) the genre:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE genre LIKE '%comedy%' ORDER BY dateadded DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE genre LIKE '%comedy%' ORDER BY dateadded DESC";
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE FIND_IN_SET('comedy', genre) ORDER BY dateadded DESC";
```

Second one is better in most cases.

Even better, you should use a **separate** table for facilitating many-to-many relationships.

i.e. New table called 'movies_genres' with two fields - movie_id and genre_id (both indexed foreign keys). Every time you add a new genre to a movie or a new movie to a genre, add an entry to this table.

To find all movies belonging to a particular genre:

```
SELECT movies.*
FROM movies
    JOIN movies_genres
        ON movies_genres.movie_id = movies.id
    JOIN genres
        ON movies_genres.genre_id = genres.id
WHERE genres.name = 'comedy'
```

To find all genres belonging to a particular movie:

```
SELECT genres.*
FROM genres
    JOIN movies_genres
        ON movies_genres.genre_id = genres.id
    JOIN topics
        ON movies_genres.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movies.name = 'Citizen Kane'
```

Answer (score 1):

With your schema you might be interested in [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT
  x,y,z
FROM
  movielist
WHERE
  find_in_list('comedy', genre)
```

Keep in mind that this is not [index-friendly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) and potentially slow.

---

With [normalized tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) you wouldn't have `genre='comedy, action, drama'` (i.e. structured data within one field) but a table

```
genres (
  id int auto_increment,
  genre_name varchar(...)
  ...
)
```

a table

```
movielist (
  id int auto_increment,
  title varchar(...)
  ...
)
```

and a table

```
moviegenres (
  movieid int,
  genreid int,
  ...
)
```

And a query that "glues" the information stored in these three tables together using one or two [JOINs](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0):

For an immediate solution, do a Dexter suggested. But in the long run you will get a lot of benefit from [normalizing your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)